# How to force emoji keyboard on input type=text?

Tags: html, w3c, polyfills

I am writing a polyfill for `input type=emoji` https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/495 and need to enable this keyboard on mobile browsers.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't force an emoji keyboard. it's not possible even if the mobile has the **Emoji Keyboard** with it.